# Calling $scope.apply() in k-change event [kendo, Angular]

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

I have below scroll view with paging enabled, I need to update few other views when user scrolls between pages. So i have added k-change call back event.

```
<kendo-mobile-scroll-view
             id="myScrollview" 
             k-data-source="myArray" 
             k-enable-pager="false"  
             k-page="10" 
             k-template="templates.myTemplate" 
             style="height:100%;"
             k-change="onScrollChange"
             >
</kendo-mobile-scroll-view>
```

In My Controller:

```
$scope.onScrollChange = function(event)
{
    console.log("onScrollChange called");

    .... Modify few scope variables .... 

    // To reflect changes I need to call 
    $scope.apply();
}
```

But problem is when my HTML page loads then also my `onScrollChange` is getting called and at that time if I call `$scope.apply()` then I see errors in log saying scope updating in progress and my HTML view gets disturbed.

So how can I call `$scope.apply()` on the user interaction with scroll view only to avoid this error.

If don't call `$scope.apply()` then my other view does not update.

Comment: try this  `$scope.$apply();`

Comment: Fixed it by adding `k-on-change="onScrollChange"` instead of ` k-change="onScrollChange"`